# GetFeatureInfo with leaflet.extras2 and Shiny

Tags: leaflet, getfeatureinfo, shiny

I am building an R Shiny App that utilizes the following WMS. However, the GetFeatureInfo capabilities for click-enabled popup (leaflet.extras2 functionality) returns a summary of the GetCapabilities. Changing the GetCapabilities to GetFeatureInfo request for the WMS url does not provide any functionality. I have contacted the WMS admin and they GetFeatureInfo is reportedly enabled. Any reasons why it wouldn't be working in with this WMS? I have no previous experience working with WMS.

Additionally, the WMS layer does not show in the map window when this popup (image attached) functionality is enabled. However, ending the WMS url at: https://ortho.gis.iastate.edu/arcgis/services/ortho/lidar_dem_3m/ImageServer/WMSServer allows map visualization but not popup functionality.

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(leaflet.extras2) # built in GetFeatureInfo
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(XML)
```

```
leaflet() %>%
  setView(lng = -93.6319,
          lat = 42.0308,
          zoom = 12) %>%
  leaflet.extras2::addWMS(
    # "https://ortho.gis.iastate.edu/arcgis/services/ortho/lidar_dem_3m/ImageServer/WMSServer", # working alternative
    "https://ortho.gis.iastate.edu/arcgis/services/ortho/lidar_dem_3m/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service", 
    layers = "lidar_dem_3m",
    options = WMSTileOptions(
      format = "image/png",
      version = "1.3.0",
      transparent = T,
      info_format = "text/xml" 
    ),
    group = "dem3",
    popupOptions = popupOptions(maxWidth = 300, closeOnClick = T)
  ) %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("dem3"))
```

[image]

Comment: Running your code, the popup says "Unknown service requested."... did something change on the server since when you posted your question?